# How to execute few steps before each feature file and after feature file in Cucumber+JVM+Junit project

Tags: selenium, junit, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I want to execute few DB connection script to get user list before each test class and close db connection after complete of all test case of test class.
Mean want to execute Before feature and after feature.

I had tried to use @BeforeClass and @AfterClass of Junit  in my step definition file where all test are written in given when and then format.
But @BeforeClass and @AfterClass were not executing  . Please help me

Comment: can you post code snippet please?

Answer (score 0):

```
@BeforeClass
   public void setStatusOfLoggedInUser() throws IOException
   {
       LoginUsers ObjLoginUsers = new LoginUsers();
       getUserName=ObjLoginUsers.getAvaiableUser();
      ObjLoginUsers.SetStatusOfLoggedInUser(getUserName);
   } 
   @AfterClass
   public static void resetStatusOfLoggedInUser() throws IOException
   {
       LoginUsers ObjLoginUsers= new LoginUsers();
       String Status="False";
       ObjLoginUsers.ResetStatusOfLoggedInUser(Status,getUserName);

   }
```